# Laravel: Problema al crear una migración para agregar dos nuevas columnas únicas

Tags: laravel, mariadb, migration

tengo un problema al momento de crear dos nuevas columnas en mi base de datos. Quiero que sean de valores únicos y para ello aplique el siguiente código:

```
$table->string('mu_document', 10)->unique();
$table->string('mu_getsoft_code', 10)->unique();
```

Pero al ejecutar la migración pasan 2 cosas. La primera es que me crea las columnas en la base pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'master_users_mu_document_unique' (SQL: alter table `master_users` add unique `master_users_mu_document_unique`(`mu_document`))
```

Y segundo pese a que se crean los campos como la migración devuelve un error, no me deja hacer rollback y por ende debo eliminar manualmente los campos de la base.

Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya lo solucioné el problema era que los campos se estaban creando como not null y por ende eso traía problemas al ser dos campos nuevos en la base que no contenían información.

Actualicé el código de la siguiente manera y ya sirvió

```
$table->string('mu_document', 10)->nullable(true)->unique();
$table->string('mu_getsoft_code', 10)->nullable(true)->unique();
```